# using find to do multiple commands

Tags: unix, find

I have a directory with many files. I can `ls z* > file` to list the files beginning with z. I can `cat z*>> file` to concatenate the files into a single file.
How can I create a single file which contains the name of the file followed by  its contents for each of the `z*` files?

Comment: A simple for loop will work: `for f in $(ls z*) ; do echo "$f:" ; cat $f ; echo "\n\n" ; done >file`

Comment: @r3mainer This should be an answer. Don't parse the output of `ls`. Better use `for f in z* ; ...`. See [Bash Pitfalls: `for f in $(ls *.mp3)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)